# How to map models names attributes with reative forms attributes - Angular 6

Tags: angular

So imagine that I have a form like:

```
myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      thing: this.formBuilder.group({
        att1: [[], []],
        att2: ['', []],
        att3: [[], []]
      })
    }, { updateOn: 'blur' });
```

and a model like this:

```
export interface Thing{

    att1:string;
    att2:string;
    att3:string;


    }
```

How can I set my form in my model?

```
newThing={
att1: this.myform.get('thing.att1).value;
...
}
```

This is not a good way of doing this. How can I set my form in my model in the best way possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "set my form in my model"?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the value of your form to your model?

Comment: @AsimHasmi exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value` property of your form and you can assign it like this:

```
newThing = this.myform.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use value propertie or you could assing element by element like this:

```
const thing : Thing = {
 att1: myForm.controls['att1'].value,
 att2: myForm.controls['att2'].value,
 att3: myForm.controls['att3'].value,
}
```

This is usefull if you don't want all the attributes of the class to be excaly the same in your Form.

And in diferent way to set an Object values in the form

```
myForm.controls['att1'].setValue(thing.att1);
```